# Creating JS variables from input value in for loop

Tags: javascript

I have this JS:

```
let streetNumber = document.getElementById('street_number').value;
let postalCode = document.getElementById('postal_code').value;
let country = document.getElementById('country').value;
```

But it's very repetitive and not really DRY in my opinion. What I would love is something like this (because I have the array available):

```
let arr = ["street_number", "postal_code", "country"];

for (entry of arr) {
   let entry = document.getElementById(entry).value;
}
```

Basically just creating JS variables for each of the input values extracted from the HTML input field.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: you can use getElementsByTagName("input") to get all the input fields.

Comment: You can't create a variable whose name comes from a runtime value. The usual solution here is to use an object or a `Map`: `const inputs = Object.fromEntries(arr.map(name => [name, document.getElementById(name).value]));` or `const inputs = new Map(arr.map(name => [name, document.getElementById(name).value]));`